# Display a list of friends with 3 states on sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I just use sails.js, it is good
I have a problem, please help me.
I have 2 collections, it is create one to many and i want to show list friends with 3 state is defined.
User:

```
attributes: {
  username: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  firstname: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  lastname: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  email: {
    type: 'string',
    email: 'true',
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },

  buddy: {
    collection: "Buddy",
    via: "buddyOf"
  }
}
```

Buddy:

```
attributes: {
  user_id: {
    type: 'string'
  },

  // 0: no friends
  // 1: waiting accept
  // 2: Cancel friend
  statusBuddy: {
    type: 'integer'
  },

  buddyOf: {
    model: 'User'
  }
}
```

I want to search user show 3 button status:
no friends, waiting accept, Cancel friend

Comment: Please reformulate the question, I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not try this code, but maybe it could be possible without having 2 models?

```
identity: 'user',
isFriendedBy: {
      collection: 'user',
      via: 'friendsWith'
    },
friendsWith: {
 model: 'user'
},
friendshipStatus: 'integer'
```